# my record is not been inserted

Tags: java, swing, oop, 3-tier

This is my form code from where i am passing the argument in my class.
this error is arising in form class

> no suitable constructor found for
>   cProperty(String,String,int,int,int,int,String,String,int,String,String,String)
>       constructor cProperty.cProperty(String,String,int,int,int,int,String,String,int,String,String,int)
>   is not applicable
>         (actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
>       constructor cProperty.cProperty() is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       try
       {
           cProperty p1=new cProperty(this.tx1.getText(),this.tx2.getText(),Integer.parseInt(this.tx3.getText()),Integer.parseInt(this.tx4.getText()),Integer.parseInt(this.tx5.getText()),Integer.parseInt(this.tx6.getText()),this.tx7.getText(),((JTextField)jDCS.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(),Integer.parseInt(this.tx8.getText()),this.tx9.getText(),((JTextField)jDCB.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(),this.tx10.getText());
           if(p1.addProperty()>0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Records inserted successfully"); 
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Records not inserted");  
            } 


       }
       catch(Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }
    }
```

This is my class where i am getting the values from form

```
public class cProperty 
{
    String AREA;
    String LOCATION;
    int UNITS_OF_MEASUREMENT;
    int NATURE;
    int TYPE;
    int SELLER;
    String SELLER_PRICE;
    String SELLER_DATE;
    int BUYER;
    String BUYER_PRICE;
    String BUYER_DATE;
    int AGENT;


    public cProperty()
    {

    }

    public cProperty(String area,String location,int uom,int nature, int type, int seller, String sprice, String sdate, int buyer, String bprice, String bdate, int agent)
    {
    AREA=area;
    LOCATION=location;
    UNITS_OF_MEASUREMENT=uom;
    NATURE=nature;
    TYPE=type;
    SELLER=seller;
    SELLER_PRICE=sprice;
    SELLER_DATE=sdate;
    BUYER=buyer;
    BUYER_PRICE=bprice;
    BUYER_DATE=bdate;
    AGENT=agent;
    }

    public int addProperty()
    {
        try
        {
            cDBcon db1 =new cDBcon();
            String qry="Insert into PROPERTY(AREA,LOCATION,UNITS_OF_MEASUREMET,NATURE,TYPE,SELLER,SELLER_PRICE,SELLER_DATE,BUYER,BUYER_PRICE,BUYER_DATE,AGENT) VALUES ('"+AREA+"','"+LOCATION+"','"+UNITS_OF_MEASUREMENT+"','"+NATURE+"','"+TYPE+"','"+SELLER+"','"+SELLER_PRICE+"','"+SELLER_DATE+"','"+BUYER+"','"+BUYER_PRICE+"','"+AGENT+"')";

             return db1.UDI(qry);            
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `this.tx10.getText()` is of type `String`, convert to `int`.

Comment: @Izma I don't understand why you posted the question, the error is LITERALLY pointing the problem x) I don't know if there is a flag for this?

Comment: Ugly, unreadable code.  Learn and follow the Java coding standards.

Comment: @duffymo The class members in caps? It's still ok imo, as they're in english and explicit.

Comment: the error is been removed but the record is not been inserted

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions Learn about java coding convention

Comment: Not ok.  Not standard.

Answer (score 0):

> actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation
>   conversion

`this.tx10.getText()` is of type `String`, should convert it to `int`

Try

```
Integer.parseInt(this.tx10.getText())
```

instead

```
this.tx8.getText()
```